# Display number of messages in linux mail queue

Tags: linux, email, queue

Is there a simple command to find out the current number of messages in the linux mail queue? `mailq` dumps out a verbose list, but it's not convenient for a quick overview.

I'm using Ubuntu and postfix.

Comment: What mail transfer agent are you using?

Comment: like bart said, tell us what MTA youre using so we can give you a more specific and correct approch.

Comment: sendmail, sorry.

Comment: Sure it's sendmail, not postfix? Just making sure...

Comment: good catch, its postfix not sendmail.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you just want to know the number of messages sitting in the deferred queue, then the following should get you a quick answer:

```
find /var/spool/postfix/deferred -type f | wc -l
```

There are three other queues.  See http://www.porcupine.org/postfix/queueing.html for details.

Comment: in my case it was this:
`find /var/spool/mqueue -type f | wc -l` and this `find /var/spool/mqueue-rx -type f | wc -l` as I have two queues and don't use postfix.

Answer (score 18):

You could filter the output and display only the last line:

```
mailq | tail -n 1
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, but the queue is massive, so it take's a long time to return a result. Anything faster..?

Comment: If the queue is really really massive, there may be another issue (unless you're an ISP or mail hosting service). You shouldn't have a backup so huge that you have to wait a few minutes for these results...?

Comment: I'm sure there is another issue, but that'll come in another question ;)

Answer (score 4):

As a related matter, you can also obtain the number of messages in your mailbox stored in mbox format, by modifying Brian Showalter's suggestion using the command "mail --headers."   For example, I have this line in my .bashrc file:

```
if [ -s /var/mail/$(whoami) ] ; then echo -e "\nYou have $(ls -s -h /var/mail/$(whoami) | cut -d" " -f 1) of mail.  Number of messages: $(mail --file /var/mail/$(whoami) --headers | wc -l) ($(mail --file /var/mail/$(whoami) --headers | sed '/^>* *[0-9]/d' | wc -l) unread)" ; fi
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is

> ```
> find /var/spool/postfix/deferred -type f | wc -l
> ```

good idea, but it doesn't work if my Zabbix-Agent isn't run as a root. So I used this

```
NUM=`mailq | grep -E "Requests" | awk '{print $5}'`; if [ -z "$NUM" ]; then echo "0"; else echo $NUM; fi
```

for my own UserParameter.